# Strings to list and loop checking

Tags: python, python-3.x

---

Given a list, containing N user-provided strings, the task is to print whether each string is a palindrome or not. (PYTHON)

i have this code already. and keeps telling me errors that "Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\jpsam\Desktop\fuckmylife.py", line 20, in <module>
    palindrome_checker(q)
  File "C:\Users\jpsam\Desktop\fuckmylife.py", line 4, in palindrome_checker
    while y <len(inputlist()):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

def palindrome_checker(q):

   y = 0
    while y <len(inputlist()):
        if inputlist == inputlist[::-1]:
            print(q, " is a panlindrome")
            len(inputlist()-1)
        else:
            print (q, "not a palindrome")
            len(inputlist()-1)
        return (q)

x = 1
inputlist = []
while x == 1:
    q = input("Input string: ")
    inputlist.append(q)
    x = int(input("Do you want to add more? [1]YES [0]NO ====>"))

palindrome_checker(q)
```

Comment: Please paste the *exact* error message and traceback. "keeps telling me errors" is not a useful error message!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpsam\Desktop\fuckmylife.py", line 9, in <module>
    s = inputlist()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant information, don't put it in the comments where it's hard to find and hard to read.

Comment: It might seem hard to edit a question, but it isn't really - and you can always cancel an attempted edit if you don't know how to achieve what yo want. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

First, your indentation is incorrect.

Secondly, the statement `len(inputlist()-1)` is giving the exception because you have followed a list, `inputlist`, with `()`, which asks the interpreter to call `inputlist` as a function. Unfortunately I have no idea what this statement is supposed to achieve (not the other one in the `if` branch - your code could be refactored too).

A simpler palindrome function might read as follows:

```
def palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

You might use it as follows:

```
if palindrome("able I was ere I saw elba"):
    print("The phrase is palindromic")
```